# jQuery object initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm not even quite sure what the correct vocabulary is for this, but I have the following code:

```
$(this).mySpecialMethod({
    propertyOne: "ValueOne",
    propertyTwo: "ValueTwo"
});
```

I'd like to dynamically control passing in a special **`propertyThree: "ValueThree"`** to this depending on other properties on the page/control.

How do I declare an object, add new properties to it based on my requirements and then pass it to the above specified method?

Comment: What you're actually doing here is passing an object (defined using [object literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects)) as an argument to the function `mySpecialMethod()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an object like this:

```
var myObj = {
    propertyOne: "ValueOne",
    propertyTwo: "ValueTwo"
}
```

and then add to it as many properties as you want using the right syntax, like this:

```
if (/* some condition */) {
    myObj.propertyThree = "ValueThree";
}
```

Now you can pass the object you created to your method:

```
$(this).mySpecialMethod(myObj);
```

---

I suggest you to **take a look at [the MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)** about Objects in JavaScript: you may find it helpful.

Comment: I will upvote this answer as its more descriptive than mine. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try as follows:

```
var options = {
    propertyOne: "ValueOne",
    propertyTwo: "ValueTwo"
};

if (conditionIWant === true) {
    options.propertyThree = 'ValueThree';
}

$(this).mySpecialMethod(options);
```